# How is xmlhttp.responseText assigned before xmlhttp.send()

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, events

Newbie ajax question from [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_post):
How is xmlhttp.responseText assigned before xmlhttp.open() and xmlhttp.send() ? (If we need the data from demo_post.asp)

I understand it is in the onreadystatechange but if the javascript is read from top down I do not understand. Thanks, and go easy on me!

Comment: I’d suspect .responstText is just empty

Comment: @Dormilich: Based on Jack's tip - the behavior of the onready..() is just defined here. It will be called on sent() or if anything changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look into closures.

onreadystatechange is getting assigned a function. That function is not called immediately...look at its name.